# Sliding window that increases

Tags: python, python-2.7, sliding-window

I want to get a sliding window that does not 'slide' but just increases such as if the width was 1 for sequence 'ATCGATCGA' I want to receive these:
(A)(A,T)(A,T,C)(A,T,C,G)(A,T,C,G,A)(A,T,C,G,A,T)(A,T,C,G,A,T,C)(A,T,C,G,A,T,C,G)(A,T,C,G,A,T,C,G,A)

Ideally I want it to start sliding with 9 hence why in the code I have been working on it n=1+8+i. I figured that by enumerating the sliding it would add on each time and therefore increase but the error below occurs

Attempted code:

```
def Slide_merge (seq):
    n=1+8+i
    it= iter(seq)
    for i, in enumerate(list(islice(it, n))):
        print it
        print n
```

Error message:

```
<ipython-input-1-80c92e1a3f14> in Slide_merge(seq)
      1 import itertools
      2 def Slide_merge (seq):
----> 3     n=1+8+i
      4     it= iter(seq)
      5     for i, in enumerate(list(islice(it, n))):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: The code you've posted and the code shown in error message are different.

Comment: I don't think the last code snippet is really relevant to the error, but the first snippet is indeed the one causing the error described

Comment: @200 Ok that was because I had continued editing it, have placed it back to the original now as well so they match.

Comment: @logc I have removed the last code, was unsure if relevant or not so figured may as well put it in.

Comment: @Tom Google the error message, it has been asked like million times.

Comment: @200 Ok I realise the error has been asked so many times and I realise the issue. The issue is that I am new to python and so am unaware of another method to create an extending sliding window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about slicing the sequence yourself?

```
In [12]: def slide_merge(seq):
   ....:     for i in range(1, len(seq)):
   ....:         print seq[0:i]
   ....:

In [13]: slide_merge('ATCGATCGA')
A
AT
ATC
ATCG
ATCGA
ATCGAT
ATCGATC
ATCGATCG
```